# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(1 + \sin^4(x))\sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

**How would you calculate the integral without using identities involving integrals/hyper geometric functions?**
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(1 + \sin^4(x))\sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}}\, dx
\end{align}

$(t = \sin(x))$, so $(dt = \cos(x) dx)$

$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1 + t^4)\sqrt{1 + t^2}}, dt)$

$\sqrt{1 + t^2} = \sqrt{t^2(1 + t^{-2})} = |t|\sqrt{1 + t^{-2}})$

$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(1 + t^4)|t|\sqrt{1 + t^{-2}}}$

After some more substitution i got this
$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{1}{u^3(1 + u)} $

But after evaluating the integral doesn't give me the answer that we needed

Comment: In the first substitution, you forgot to include the term $\sqrt{1 - t^2}$ in the denominator corresponding to $\cos(x)$.

Comment: We have that $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{(1+\sin^4(x))\sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}}\textrm{d}x=\frac{1}{8} \left(\pi +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\right)$, and problem is given and solved in  **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019)**, pages $263$-$267$.

Comment: @user97357329 thanks alot

Comment: Here is a very simple solution by Sujeethan Balendran: https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=1084625245207435&set=pb.100009799095439.-2207520000

Comment: @user97357329. Thanks for the nice result and the link. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Welcome! Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sudeep5221 commented, you missed a term when you used the first subtitution
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{(1 + \sin^4(x))\sqrt{1+\sin^2(x)}}$$

$$t=\sin(x) \quad \implies I=\int\frac{dt}{ \left(1+t^4\right)\sqrt{1-t^4}}$$

There is an explicit solution but it involves either elliptic integrals or  Appell hypergeometric functions of two variables.

Probably, for the time being, use a series expansion

$$\frac{1}{ \left(1+t^4\right)\sqrt{1-t^4}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\,\frac {a_n}{b_n} \, t^{4n}$$ where the $a_n$ and $b_n$ form respectively sequences $A123746$ and $A046161$ in $OEIS$.

The problem is that the convergence is extremely slow if you integrate termwise between $0$ and $1$.

**Edit**

Just to give an idea of the complexity of the result, the definite integral is
$$-\sqrt{\pi }\,\,\frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)} \left(4+\frac{1+i}{2}
   B_{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right)  \right)$$

Comment: How would you show this equals $\frac18\big(\pi+\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Gamma(\frac14)^2\big)$?

Comment: @ТymaGaidash٠ Absolutely no idea ! What about you ? Cheers :-)